# Where will FC Barcelona play if Catalonia gets independence?

Tags: football, la-liga

So what will happen to clubs like Espanyol and Barcelona if Catalonia gets independence? Will they continue in La Liga or play in another league? Are there any official announcements regarding this matter?

Comment: Only an assumption, but I believe it would be like Swansea and Cardiff playing in the English football league system, or Monaco in France.

Comment: Opinions have been stated by Spanish football and political authorities (see answers below), therefore I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: This question should be reopened. There are clear statements from officials from both sides about the future of the club in the case of independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a coincidence, or maybe you read something about it today(most likely i guess)

But last night Spanish football president, Javier Tebas [announced](http://www.marca.com/en/2015/09/21/en/football/spanish_football/1442853290.html) that Catalan teams would not be able to participate in the Spanish football league. Something he has done [before](http://www.marca.com/en/2014/10/07/en/football/spanish_football/1412680848.html) apparently. Also Spanish Sports Council president agreed on it.

As regulated by Spanish sport laws, only teams from Andorra can compete in the Spanish (football) leagues as non-Spanish clubs. For that law to change there as to be a vote by the Spanish parliament, which might not be keen on letting them in as kind of repercussion.

But on the other hand I(!) can't not think they would allow them to participate in the end. *For good measure, my humble opinion*!